# DynamoDB - Extract date and Query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am having the following table in my DynamoDB.
[image: DDB Table]
I want to get/extract all the data using the following condition or filters

- **This Month data** : This will be the set of records that belongs to 1st of this month to today. ( I think this I can achieve using the `BEGINS_WITH` filter , again not sure whether this is the correct approach )
- **This Quarter data** : This will be the set of records that belongs to this quarter, basically from 1st of April 2021 to 30th June 2021
- **This Year data** : This will be set of records that belongs to this entire year

**Question :** How I can filter/query the data using the `date` column from the above table to get these 3 types (Month , Quarter ,Year ) of data.

**Other Details**

- Table Size : 25 GB
- Item Count : 4,081,678

Comment: There are up to 5 components in the column: date1-date2|x|y|z. What do you exactly use to tell if a row is less 30 days old?

Comment: Basically I want to convert date1-date2 to a range filter , so that I can query on the date range.

Comment: You won't be able to "extract" the dates from an arbitrary attribute using the DynamoDB API.  If `uuid` is your sort key (aka range key), you'd be able to use the `between` keyword to compare dates.  Really hard to say what you should do without understanding how your table and primary keys are set up.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan I have edited the entire question with more details

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have time-based access patterns (e.g. fetch by month, quarter, year, etc).

Because your sort key starts with a date, you can implement your access patterns using the `between` condition on your sort key. For example (in pseudo code):

Fetch User 1 data for this month

> query where user_id = 1 and date between 2021-06-01 and 2021-06-30

Fetch User 1 data for this quarter

> query where user_id = 1 and date between 2021-01-01 and 2021-03-31

Fetch User 1 data for this month

> query where user_id = 1 and date between 2021-06-01 and 2021-06-30

If you need to fetch across *all* users, you could use the same approach using the `scan` operation. While `scan` is commonly considered wasteful/inefficient, it's a fine approach if you run this type of query infrequently.

However, if this is a common access pattern, you might want to consider re-organizing your data to make this operation more efficient.

Comment: thank you for your inputs, you are right this design is not correct. I did some changes to the flow ( Table design , Lambda etc ), I am posting the details in the answer. Hopefully it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above answer by **@Seth Geoghegan** , the above table design is not correct, ideally you should think before placing your `Partition Key` and `Sort Key`, still for the people like me who already have such kind of scenarios, here is the steps which I followed to mitigate my issue.

- Enabled DynamoDB Steams
- Re-trigger the data so that they can pass through the DDB Streams ( I added one additional column `updated_dttm` to all of my records using one of the script )
- Process the Streams record , in my case I broken down the `date` column above to three more columns , `event_date` , `category` , `sub_category` respectively and updated back to the original record using the Lambda

Then I was able to query my data using `event_date` column , I can also create index over `event_date` column and make my query/search more effective

**Points to Consider**

- Cost for updating records so that they can go to DDB Streams
- Cost of reprocessing the records
- Cost for updating records back to DDB